# Reference includes files in ColdBox module

Tags: coldbox

I've created a module `foo` that has an `includes` directory, which in turn contains a `js` directory, which has a file in it named `edit.js`.

I've tried the following in a view of the module:

```
<script src="/myApp/foo/includes/js/edit.js"></script>
```

But I get a 404.

What's the proper way to reference modules' static assets?

Answer (score 2):

Just took a bit more searching:

```
<script src="#event.getModuleRoot()#/includes/js/edit.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
<script src="#event.buildLink('')#includes/js/edit.js"></script>
```